# remove hidden column save excel range to csv

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I did code to save excel range to csv
but its getting hidden columns also can somebody help to remove hidden column?

```
'Sub to select range from excel and save it as CSV
'Added code for paste special    
Private Sub Main()
    Dim sFullFilePath As String
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    sFullFilePath = "C:\MyFileName.csv"
    Set selectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)

    RangeTOCsv sFullFilePath, selectedRange
End Sub

Private Sub RangeTOCsv(sFullFilePath As String, selectedRange As Range)
    Dim workBook As workBook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    selectedRange.Copy
    Set workBook = Workbooks.Add
    With workBook
        .Sheets(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs sFullFilePath, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `RangeToCsv` procedure like below:

```
Private Sub RangeToCsv(sFullFilePath As String, selectedRange As Range)
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim Workbook As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set rng = selectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set Workbook = Workbooks.Add
    With Workbook
        Call rng.Copy
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs sFullFilePath, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Before the selected range is pasted into new workbook, it is being filtered by function `SpecialCells` with parameter `Type` set to `xlCellTypeVisible`.

After this operation, variable `rng` stores all the visible cells from the original `selectedRange` range.

Comment: Thanks mielk :) i slightly changed it. I changed it before sending to function RangeTOCsv sFullFilePath, selectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)